# Select only direct children of an element, regardless of tag name

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a simple structure that looks like this:

```
<p class="container">
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p class="lead">...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</p>
```

And I need to select `h2`, `p.lead` and `p`. Since `p.container` may contain any tags, simple hard listing won't be a good solution (although, acceptable).

So what is a CSS selector syntax that would allow me select `p.container`'s children but not their children (e.g. not `p.subcontainer *`)?

Answer (score 3):

Use an [**Universal Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) `*`, combined with a [**Child Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)  `>`:

```
p.container > * {
    /*style*/
}
```

And, in case you don't want to select the `subcontainer` one, exclude it with the `:not()` selector:

```
p.container > *:not(.subcontainer) {
    /*style*/
}
```